# Recover a disk after failed gparted resize

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, ubuntu-10.04, gparted

I was trying to resize an external ntfs hard drive, so that I could make room at the front of the disk for a swap partition. At the end of the process gparted encountered an error. It couldn't see my disk again until I rebooted the system. Now, when it looks at the hard drive, it sees it as one big unpartitioned hard drive.

I'm pretty sure all the data is still there, uncorrupted. I just can't access it. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used some old tools from Acronis (I don't remember the whole name), but you can try this utity:
[Partition recovery](http://www.partition-recovery.com/overview.htm)

Or you can try to use this utility under Linux:
[PartImage](http://www.partimage.org/Main_Page) .
If you have no idea how to start it - the most simplest way is Live CD [SystemRescueCD](http://www.sysresccd.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I would use testdisk, that way you can retrieve just the files you need. If you have the space, always use the Linux/UNIX dd utility to make a backup of your disk. If you use gzip compression, any unused space or text files should compress very well.

dd example with gzip compression (make sure the drive is NOT mounted first):

```
mount | grep [/dev/sdb|`vol_id --uuid /dev/sdb`]
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb | gzip -c > /path/to/image.img
```

now you can run testdisk (exits for Windows, Mac OS X, and Linux among other platforms)

```
sudo testdisk /dev/sdb
```

or if you want to select the drive:

```
sudo testdisk
```

Follow the instructions ...

See http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk for more inforation on testdisk and http://ss64.com/bash/dd.html for more info on dd.

Comment: Wait - testdisk can read a Gzipped disk image?

Comment: No, it cannot, the gzip file is your backup. I instruct you to run `testdisk` against `/dev/sdb` which is a drive.